# Add annotation/descriptive label to each subplot in pairs

Tags: r, annotations, label

I have pairs of several data sets and I want to add the correlation coefficient to each one so that the correlations can be visually seen. Ex:

```
corr1 <- cor(richstruc[,c(4,10,11)])
pairs(richstruc[,c(4,10,11)], main = "comparison 1")
```

Is there any way I can add the annotations "p = (the corresponding value from corr1)" to each corresponding subplot in the pair?

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Using the argument `panel`, you can control what will be displayed in each panel. You can customize that to add a marginal label. I increased the margin size (`gap=2`) and decreased the font size (`cex=0.8`) to make the text fit. Since you do not provide your data,  I will illustrate with the built-in iris data.

```
Display = function(x,y) {
    points(x,y, pch=16, col=rainbow(3)[iris$Species])
    CXY = round(cor(x,y), 3)
    mtext(paste("cor =", CXY), 1, cex=0.8)
}
pairs(iris[1:3], panel=Display, gap=2)
```

[image: Pairs with correlations]